# Pages except index.html not working. How to add multiple pages on git bash?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me with this- after deploying multiple pages,  the only **`index.html`** is working while other pages I have named as **`index1.html`** and so on. So how do I add these multiple pages on git bash? The page index.html shows up nothing else but at the local end it does, so what should I name not every page can be index  please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are adding `index.html` using: `git add index.html`

you can add your entire working directory, i.e., ***all*** of your files in your directory using:

```
git add .
```

firther reasding: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

conversely, if you wish to `commit` all these files in one step:

```
git commit -a
```